# broken packages when trying to install phablet-tools

Tags: 12.04

I can not install phablet-tools.

```
phablet-tools : Depends: click but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is response I get from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with adding the `not going to be installed` package to the installation list:

```
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools click
```